# Combining Feeds (with teasers) on the homepage?

Tags: feeds, nodes

I want to combine several feeds (several internal blogs from my site and several external feeds) and post them on the homepage.  I want to use teasers to only show part of each post.

How should I do this?

I have been trying to use the aggregator module and the feeds_block that it creates out of all the feeds, however it shows the entire posts. I want teasers.

Answer (score 0):

I used the aggregator module and then added the Views block called "feed_block" on the homepage (and only the homepage).  So the blog posts appear just below my introduction to our organization page (that is published to front and stickied).

The aggregator module has all of my external feeds (from other sites). It combines them into a category (I'm not sure if this part is necessary).

The homepage then displays everything from aggregator and also any locally created blog posts (anything with a content-type of "blog").

I might replace this solution with the Feeds module - as the aggregator module does not remove items when the original item is deleted (unless you remove all items and them update them for that feed). Also the feed_block has a "more" link that is broken. It links to the www.domain.org page, when it should link to the node.